# Android Notifications with customized appearance

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

As of now, I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging as my app's notification system. From my understanding, even the largest companies use GCM, which is now being replaced with FCM. I am stuck, however, with the limitations imposed by sending things as a "notification" pay load.

Firebase recieves **data** messages in OnMessageRecieved, and I am able to get my exact desired behavior through using this. However, for the past three months I noticed that my app's notifications were simply not working because data payloads aren't received when the app is in the background/ inactive. This is very frustrating as the only workaround I have found to actually send notifications that alert users is through sending **notification** payloads.

I don't know how to get my desired behavior with the notification payload as I have been with data payload, but I realize that having notifications display perfectly when the app is in the foreground is pointless if they don't display at all when the app is in the background.

What I'm wondering, and what I'd really appreciate guidance on, is if somebody could recommend a way to display notifications with my desired style rather than the default Firebase **notification** style. Just to elaborate, I currently have a fully functional system of allowing users to respond to messages through the notification and without opening the app, but only through the **data** payload.

I know there is a way to somehow send notifications in a customized fashion (adding intents, buttons, etc) when the app is in the background or not running because this is done by Facebook, WhatsApp, and many other apps on the market. I am aware of something called AlarmManagers, but unsure of how I could use them to get my desired behavior, or if this is what people use anyways.

Thank you, and please let me know if there is a way to customize the payload when the app is in the background or inactive, through onMessagesRecieved or any other methods. As of now, the only other solution would be to somehow send the message's contents to a service, but I've faced issues where services could not display notifications in the background without crashing the app and without being very hacky.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I came up with is to send the data payload only, which should be delivered to the onMessageReceived callback despite the app's status (foreground/background).

Then you put all required fields to the data payload and build a notification from it. Here the map "data" is from remoteMessage.getData()

```
private void sendNotification(Map<String, String> data) {
    String body = Optional.ofNullable(data.get("body")).orElse("");
    if (body.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri sound = getSoundUri(Optional.ofNullable(data.get("sound")).orElse(""));
    String defaultChannel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
                                ? NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID
                                : DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID;

    String channel = Optional.ofNullable(data.get("android_channel_id")).orElse(defaultChannel);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(body)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setShowWhen(true)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    if (sound != null)
        notificationBuilder.setSound(sound);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (notificationManager != null)
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```